# @Html.DropDownListFor Binding with no model

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

is it possible to bind the DropdownListFor with a property of an object that is not part of the Model?

For exemple:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => object.Property[i].Value,
new SelectList(ListItem, "Value", "Text"),
"Select...",)
```

I correctly display the list in the front-end, but the selected value does not go into binding. How come?

Thanks

Comment: the controller will bind according to the name attribute of the select methinks... check the select tag in inspector to see what that name is set to.  (or possibly the id attribute)

Comment: normally speaking, we need to bind the value to model so that when we submit data, we could receive model value in Controller...Could you pls let us know why you want to bind to an object which is not in the model ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Kzd.png

Comment: Because it will be the properties of that object that will pass to the controller, not the model.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible as we have to set a model when we write the `DropDownListFor`, or we might get exception like this.  By the way, do you want to write your controller action like `public xxx getData(Model model, object obj)`? And you could put some extra data in the object instead of model? If so, I still recommend modifying the model to put all the data into the model.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfye7.png